# Linked scenes with different materials in blender 2.82++

Tags: linked-data, scene

I need to have two scenes exactly the same. The only difference will be the material of each object. It is important to have all the elements between scenes linked so any change in one scene is also applied in the other. This is in order to have an automatic script to generate the instance segmentation image of the scene.

I could copy the scene when rendering, change the materials and remove the scene and repeat every time the user renders, but having a linked scene is much cleaner. I have followed several similar questions which suggest to link the material to the object and not the data. This looks like not working maybe because it works different in linked copies of a scene or maybe because it is blender 2.82.

Any idea how to achieve this? Thanks everyone

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to create a duplicate of any new object and link it with the 2nd scene and also link the object data of the original and duplicate.

Then you can just link the materials to object instead of data.

Comment: Can you elaborate of how to do it? I am kind of new in blender so that would be very helpful. thanks